# 你老竇個仔, is it a minced oath in this case? If so what would be the original meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm talking specifically about [this scene](https://streamable.com/kand1). I'm trying to translate this to english but as of now I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Cantonese swearing can be very vicious and graphic sometimes.

The most common Cantonese swearing is 「我(F)你老母」and one of a variants is 「我 (F) 你老母個 臭化(C)」; 臭化 means smelly and rotten.

> 「你老竇個仔」 is a minced oath for 「你老母個 (C) 」, short for 「我(F)你老母個 (C)」

Replacing "老母" (mother) with "老竇" (father), and replacing the Cantonese "C" word with a similar sounding word "仔"

To translate it into English, you can use any minced oat, as long as it expresses strong disapproval.

For example: "Gat Dangit" --> "God damn it"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a doubt about notation: what do (C) and (F) stand for?

Comment: Google F word and C word

Comment: Well, might as well.  F= fuck; C = cunt

Comment: thanks for being this explicit

Comment: Among all the dialect groups, it is "generally recognized" that the Cantonese have the most "colorful" and numerous swear words and phrases. Maybe it's because their "language" has the most number of tonal variations? No offence Tang Ho and all other Cantonese around here or elsewhere.

Comment: 唔使介意，廣東粗口出咗名多花樣。其實淫猥不堪，不甚入耳嘅粗口喺其他方言也一定不少，相信其他省份人仕可以提供例子

Comment: A good reference. https://evchk.wikia.org/zh/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E6%9D%B1%E7%B2%97%E5%8F%A3%E4%BA%94%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%97

Comment: I knew someone would down vote my answer. Not for inaccuracy but for dare to treat  profanity as part of the language and explain it professionally